# Problem drawing horizontal line above two columns, line runs through column

Tags: spacing, rules

I'm somewhat of a beginner in LateX. I want to draw a horizontal line below my abstract to clearly separate it from the rest of the two-column text. When I do so however, the left column starts below the line, as it should, but the right column doesn't start low enough and the line runs right through it. I've looked around stackexchange but cannot seem to find an answer. How do I make the second column appear lower?

[image: The problem:]

Minimal reproducible example below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot that's just a long way of writing `\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.4pt‌​}` the makebox isn't doing anything.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right.

Comment: @marmot when I use columnwidth, the line appears only above the first column (I tried this with linewidth too). I want the line to be as long as both columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could quite well be an overkill.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
\begin{strip}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\end{strip}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly. i hadn't heard of the cuted package before but it seems it was just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The optional argument fur `\rule` raises it above the baseline.  The length `\topskip` is the distance from the top of a column to the first baseline.  Macro `\rlap` (right overlap) takes up no horizontal space.  In fact, it can execute in vmode, so no \noindent is needed.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\rlap{\rule[\topskip]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}%

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-6]

\end{document}
```